# reducing the length of character array

Tags: java, arrays, char

I have a char array in string of say length 8,Its filled with 8 characters.Now i want that it should be reduced to size 5. in C we do it by putting null in end how can we do it in  java?

Comment: It was a long time ago since I last used C, but putting null after the 5th character does not reduce the size of the array in C. It just says that there is no more data after that (if I recall it correctly)

Comment: yes , but in C  character array is string and if u print that character array elemets after c will not be printed

Answer (score 3):

In Java, you normally wouldn't use a character array.  You'd just use a String, so it'd be something like this:

```
String big = "12345678";
String little = big.substring(0, 5);
// little now equals "12345"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String s = "12345678";
char[] c = new char[5];
System.arraycopy(s.toCharArray(), 0, c, 0, 5);
```

is one way...